# ESP8266 TCPDump only arp but no tcp

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, tcp, sniffing

I have a problem with sniffing a ESP8266. I use a raspberry pi 3 as wifi access point (no wpa in use), a laptop as a server and the esp to communicate to the server.

When I use tcpdump on my raspberry with 
`tcpdump -i <interface> host <device ip> -vv`
a output is only achieved by the initial start of the esp (arp protocol) and that's it.
However, I need the http type and content/date for my purpose.

Do any of you have a solution to this?

**EDIT**
Ok I have found a solution via the use of iptables. I can define a prerouting to a specific port and listen on it with the help of tcpdump. That is really convenient and I think I can get all data I need.

Comment: I asssume the ESP8266 is connected to the RaspPi AP, say `wlan0`, and the RaspPi forwards to the laptop via LAN. What happens if you just do `tcpdump -i wlan0`? Do you see the HTTP requests? Also, google "transparent proxy" or "mitmproxy" to make the process easier.

Comment: The laptop and the esp are both in a wireless network hosted by the raspberry. When I execute the command, I get just the tcp traffic of my laptop and the start up arp traffic of the esp. Do you think a proxy would be better to sniff the communication between the server and the esp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traffic between two WLAN clients may be forwarded by the driver directly, and will in that case never reach the interface, which is why you don't see it. I don't know if it's possible to set the AP point to a mode where this traffic is also visible.

One solution is two use *two* APs, one for the ESP8266 and one for the laptop/server, and explicitely forward between them.

**Edit**

If you not only want to capture with `tcpdump`, `wireshark` etc., but inspect and modify HTTP traffic with `mitmproxy`, then it depends:

Can you tell all relevant ESP8266 applications to use the RaspPi as a proxy, with configuration or environment variables? If yes, one AP is enough.

Do you need a transparent proxy, where it will work even if you can't/don't can configure explicit proxy settings? Then you need two APs (or WLAN + LAN, or 2x LAN). No way around that. Because otherwise again any communication between the ESP8966 and the server won't leave the interface, so `mitmproxy` doesn't get to see it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think that a mitmproxy as dirkt mentioned, would be of any help? If that works, I wouldn't have to set up 2 aps and make the setup even more complex.